# kwargs1 not defined error in nvd3

Tags: python, nvd3.js

I am new to nvd3 and it's python implementation. I was trying the following line-chart given as [an example](http://python-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/classes-doc/line-chart.html) but it's returning an error that `**kwargs1` is not defined.

I don't know what it is and how to overcome this error.

```
from nvd3 import lineChart
chart = lineChart(name="lineChart", x_is_date=False, x_axis_format="AM_PM")

xdata = range(24)
ydata = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 16, 6, 9, 15, 4, 12]
ydata2 = [9, 8, 11, 8, 3, 7, 10, 8, 6, 6, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 10, 0, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "There are ", "y_end": " calls"}}
chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata, name='sine', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs1)
extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " min"}}
chart.add_serie(y=ydata2, x=xdata, name='cose', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs2)
chart.buildhtml()
```

When I try without **kwargs , then it returns `None`. Moreover, this happens with all other examples(except the pie chart)! I am unable to overcome this.

Comment: Just leave the **kwargs1 and **kwargs1 argument out; you don't need them here.

Comment: prints `none` as the output

Comment: @Evert I have tried everything possible. Still not working. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata, name='sine', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs1)
```

This line calls the add_serie method on chart, passing some parameters inside. You don't have to include **kwargs1 in the parameters passed. I think the example included it to tell you that you can pass in more parameters. To make it work, try changing the lines to:

```
chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata, name='sine', extra=extra_serie)
```

and

```
chart.add_serie(y=ydata2, x=xdata, name='cose', extra=extra_serie)
```

EDIT:
Line 2:

```
output_file = open('test-nvd3.html', 'w')
```

Append at end of file:

```
output_file.write(chart.htmlcontent)
output_file.close()
```

Check your directory for test-nvd3.html and load it in a browser.

Comment: It is not working. I don't know why it prints `none` again and again as the output. What all dependencies are required? I installed python-nvd3 and django-nvd3 too.

Comment: @PrabhjotRai Try adding the code that I've edited in my answer.

Comment: Doesn't write anything inside the html file and doesn't show anything in the browser

Comment: @PrabhjotRai Does the code at their [Introduction page](http://python-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html) work?

Answer (score 0):

This is awkward actually. If I write the following code:

```
from nvd3 import lineChart
type = 'lineChart'
chart = lineChart(name=type, x_is_date=False, x_axis_format="AM_PM")
xdata = range(24)
ydata = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 16, 6, 9, 15, 4, 12]
ydata2 = [9, 8, 11, 8, 3, 7, 10, 8, 6, 6, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 10, 0, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "There are ", "y_end": " calls"}}
chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata, name='sine', extra=extra_serie)
extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " min"}}
chart.add_serie(y=ydata2, x=xdata, name='cose', extra=extra_serie)
extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " cal"}}
chart.buildcontent()
print chart.htmlcontent
```

It works. Just the difference of that second line (`type = 'lineChart'`) but why?

Comment: No, the difference (compared to your question) is not just the second line. In fact, you should remove the second line: you're now overriding the built-in function `type` with a string. Bad idea. I see they use this in [the example in the official docs](https://python-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#usage): that's just a bad example (you can actually see that `type` is highlighted differently, like `open`, because it's a Python built-in).

Comment: Instead, the real difference is that you've now added a line `print chart.htmlcontent` at the end, which does not show in your question. Either you forget to copy a line in your question, or you fiddled too much with the file so you didn't realise what you had actually done.